# Http request are very slow with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

When I make an http from flutter to my REST API it takes around 13s to get the result while when I make an http request from my browser it takes around 0.05s.
I don't understand why the difference is so big.

Here is my code for the http request :

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' show Client;

var time1 = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
final response = await client.get(url, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
print(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - time1); // Print about 13s
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code above, can you share the API details so i can test, if something is wrong with the API

Comment: I tested it with rested and I got a correct response from the server.

Comment: let me check the API

Comment: 2019-07-12 14:19:52.944  Start
2019-07-12 14:19:53.414 {"error":false,"immeubles":[{"immeuble_id":1,"immeuble_rue":"rue d'aguesseau","immeuble_numero":129,

Comment: see, it took 500ms to get the response

Comment: So nothing with the code of flutter, you should check with  your network may be some proxy is slowing your request, or any network speed related issue might be there

Comment: Thank you i will look for that because when I try with rested on my computer it always takes less than 0.05s

Comment: BTW, you don't need to send headers, because you are not sending JSON content
just like : `client.get(url)`

Comment: Thank you, I will change it right now. I'll tell you if I find a solution to the problem.

Comment: You were right it's a problem with my mobile operator. When I use a VPN it takes only 200ms.

Comment: The real problem was with the port 8080 which was very slow on my mobile phone. I move the API on the port 5000 an it works fine.

Comment: Happy, you got the solution

Answer (score 2):

The problem is about flutter itself and iOS. At the moment it's not fixed. 
You can follow the ticket already posted on their repo [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15838)

Comment: When I had this problem, I was testing the app on an android phone. So I don't think this issue is related.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Android.